# Why are music discs failing to play any audio?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

None of the music discs make any sound, but note blocks work without any issue.

What could be causing my music disc to fail to play any audio?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What device are you playing on?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your device, you may need to **download** the music pack from the Minecraft Marketplace. Go into the Marketplace, and search up " **Music** ". Select the first thing that comes up. This should be a free download, and once it finishes, all the music should be able to start playing (Including background music as well as Music Discs).

Comment: FYI if you flag a question as duplicate it's not necessary to also answer it with an answer that basically paraphrases the answer to the duplicate.